# Find the PMF of Y if Y=X/(X+1)

Tags: probability

Suppose $X$ has the Geometric pmf $f_X(x)=\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^x, x=0,1,2,3,...$.  I am interested in finding $f_Y(y)$ if $Y=X/(X+1)$

So I'm thinking that

$$f_Y(y)=P(Y=y)=P(X/(X+1)=y)=P(1/(1+X^{-1})=y)=P(1+X^{-1}=y^{-1})$$
And so

$$=P(X^{-1}=y^{-1}-1)=P(X=1/(y^{-1}-1))=P(X=y/(y-1))=f_X\left(\frac{y}{y-1}\right)$$

But this doesn't seem right.  Would I have to find the CMF first and apply the disrete differentiation operator?

Or am I right, and the pmf for Y is

$$f_Y(y)=\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{\frac{y}{y-1}}, y=0,1/2,2/3,3/4,...$$

Comment: The resulting support is alright. But you need to be careful in the second last step: $1/(y^{-1} - 1) = y/(1 - y)$. And all other looks good.

Comment: Thank you for that.  You could write it up as an answer and I can upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only mistake is in the second last step:

$$ \frac {1} {y^{−1}−1} = \frac {y} {1−y}$$

All other looks good.